# Android DatePicker show full day names instead of short names

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Is it possible to show full week day names, instead of the short ones? When showing the calendar.

I mean instead of:

S  M  T  W  T  F  S

Show these:

Sunday  Monday  Tuesday  Wednesday  Thursday  Friday  Santurday

[image]

i have look into documentation but not able to find any suitable methods to update week name

Comment: How would you expect all those to fit on the screen, next to each other? I suspect there wouldn't even be room for "Sun Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat" without it being really squashed on most devices.

Comment: You may be happier with [another date picker library](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/27?sort=created).

Answer (score 1):

### Update 17 March

Well, as one of the users gave negative vote for the answer, I did some research and checked documentation, I found the following solution.
First you make an instance of *DatePickerDialog*

```
DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(
    this,
    new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
            // Handle the selected date
        }
    },
    year, month, dayOfMonth
);
```

Then get the *DatePicker* instance.

```
DatePicker datePicker = datePickerDialog.getDatePicker();
```

Now in this part you have to create your date format

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, MMMM dd, yyyy", Locale.getDefault());
```

Note that EEEE stands for the week full name. Check the documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/icu/text/SimpleDateFormat).

Now apply the pattern to the *DatePicker* and show the dialog.

datePicker.setDateFormatString(dateFormat.toPattern());
datePickerDialog.show();

---

Old Answer

I'm not sure about the solution. I'm writing from mind. Try to set *Locale* it may work.
After creation of your datepicker, create a new *Locale* and then apply it to your datepicker.
Looks like:

```
Locale locale = new Locale("en", "US");
datePicker.setLocale(locale);
```